# Use sed to remove key:value in yaml file

Tags: sed

I've a huge yaml fixture like this.  Is there a tidy sed one liner which can remove all the (key:value) for the products field?

```
- model: something
  pk: 777
  fields:
    created: 2015-06-10 10:16:41.142044+00:00
    modified: 2017-01-11 14:31:03.030313+00:00
    name: something
    products: [932, 3153, 3154]
- model: something2
...
```

I see I can use something like this, but how to delete up and until the first occurance of ']'?

```
sed '/^    products:/ d' < old.yaml > new.yaml
```

Comment: add expected output for clarity... `delete up and until the first occurance of ']'` starting from what/where?

Comment: There's only one set of square brackets in the example.  products: [932, 3153, 3154].  The array can be large so it spans multiple lines.  I want to remove the key products and the value which is the array.

Comment: so modify sample to include both single and multiple line (say 3 lines) and add expected output for that so that it is easier to test for those who wish to answer

Comment: Without additional constraints (like, `products` is always the last line of `model`, `products` list **never** uses the alternative representation - bullet points, etc), parsing YAML with `sed` would be very fragile and/or hard (definitively not a *one-liner*). Please use the right tool for the job. There are a plenty of YAML parsers in every language you can think of.